# What are setDefaults array options

Tags: php, symfony

What are the options for setDefaults array (data_class and ...?). Where I can found it?

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Task',
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All possible options for every form-type of the form component are listed in the documentation chapter **[Form Types Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html)**.

The baseline default options can be found in the class ...

```
Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType
```

... that all of these extend. The options are added in:

```
FormType::configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
```

Have a look at the method's implementation for Symfony 3.0 **[here](https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/3.0/Extension/Core/Type/FormType.php#L157)**.

Every form-type that comes with the form component:

- can be found under the namespace `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type`
- extends this `FormType`
- may add additional defaults inside it's `configureOptions()` method.

For example the `BirthdayType` form-type add's an option names `years`. See **[here](https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/3.0/Extension/Core/Type/BirthdayType.php#L24)**.